# display div for JQuery toggleClass

Tags: jquery

I'm trying something very simple. Upon page load the data in content div is dsplayed and menu(ul elements) are hidden. upon clicking the menu button created via css, the menu loads and the content div becomes hidden. when i click on the menu button again it hides the menu using toggleClass(). at this point its meant to display the data in the content div but this is not working as expected.

hopefully you can tell me what i'm doing wrong.

android.js:

```
// JavaScript Document
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerWidth <= 480){
    //when the document is ready run this code. wait for the page to load completely. otherwise javascript will run and because the uls don't exist
    //yet it will fail. because the js has failed the uls will load (not good)
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#header ul').addClass('hide');   //hide ul elements which is the menu on page load (see android.css #header ul.hide..)
        $('#header').append('<div class="leftButton" onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</div>');

    });


    //currently the menu (ul) elements are hidden as set on page load
    //toggleClass() works by checking what class its set to. if its already set to that class it changes it to the other.   
    function toggleMenu(){


        if($('#header ul').toggleClass('hide')){//adding hide class to the object
            $('#content').show();

        }

        if ($('#header .leftButton').toggleClass('pressed')){
            $('#content').hide();   


        }




    }



}
```

CSS file:

```
#header ul.hide{

    display:none;
}


#header div.leftButton{
    position:absolute;
    top:8.5px;
    left:6px;
    height:30px; /*set hight to 30px so its big enought to tap*/
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0px -1px 1px;
    line-height:28px; /*centers it within the div so its not up against the top border*/
    /*placing the button*/
    border-width:0 8px 0 8px;
    -webkit-border-image:url(images/button.png) 0 8 0 8;

}


#header div.pressed{
    position:absolute;
    top:8.5px;
    left:6px;
    height:30px; /*set hight to 30px so its big enought to tap*/
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0px -1px 1px;
    line-height:28px; /*centers it within the div so its not up against the top border*/
    /*placing the button*/
    border-width:0 8px 0 8px;
    -webkit-border-image:url(images/button_clicked.png) 0 8 0 8;
}


#content.hide{
    display:none;

}
```

hopefully the above is sufficient to identify why its not working. Thanks!

Comment: The [`.toggleClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) returns the same jQuery object it was called on, _not_ a boolean, so using it as an `if` condition doesn't make sense - the condition will always be true since any object is "truthy". So both the `.show()` and then the `.hide()` will run every time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i managed to fix it by doing the following:

```
function toggleMenu(){


        //$('#header ul').toggleClass('hide');//adding hide class to the object


        //$('#header .leftButton').toggleClass('pressed');
        $('#header ul').toggleClass('hide');
        $('.leftButton').toggleClass('pressed');

        if ($('#content').is(':visible')){
                $('#content').hide();

            }
        else{
            $('#content').show();


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i'm not sure if you use css to `display:none` your elements, but i'm going to go that you are calling the hide/show twice.

```
// JavaScript Document
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerWidth <= 480){
//when the document is ready run this code. wait for the page to load completely. otherwise javascript will run and because the uls don't exist
//yet it will fail. because the js has failed the uls will load (not good)
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#header ul').addClass('hide');   //hide ul elements which is the menu on page load (see android.css #header ul.hide..)
    $('#header').append('<div class="leftButton" onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</div>');

    //currently the menu (ul) elements are hidden as set on page load
    //toggleClass() works by checking what class its set to. if its already set to that class it changes it to the other.   
    function toggleMenu(){
       $('#header ul').toggleClass('hide')   
    }        


});

}
```

Another approach using jquery `toggle()`:

```
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerWidth <= 480){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header ul').css('display:none');
    $('#header').append('<div class="leftButton" onclick="toggleMenu()">Menu</div>');
    function toggleMenu(){
       $('#header ul').toggle()   
    }        


});

}
```

**Update**

Well i took the liberty to modify a little bit your html structure eliminating the onclick on the div and using pure jquery. Here is the javascript:

```
  $(function(){

     $('#header ul').addClass('hide');   //hide ul elements which is the menu on page load (see android.css #header ul.hide..)
     $('#header').append('<div class="leftButton">Menu</div>');

     $('#header').delegate('.leftButton','click',function (){
        $('#header ul').toggleClass('hide')   
     })        
 });
```

​
Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JqMYK/7/)

Comment: Thanks for that but it doesn't solve the problem. hide is infact a CSS class with `display:none`. i want to be able to hide the information in the content div when the menu is clicked and make it visible when its hidden. i'll add the css to make it clear.